# How to return specific properties from a JPA repository?

Tags: jpa, repository

I'm getting a ClassCastException when retrieving an entity into a resource. It occurs only when the JPA repository statement explicitly specifies the properties to be returned.

For example, this works just fine and there is no exception triggered:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Rollout r, RolloutAdmin ra WHERE r.id = ra.rollout.id AND ra.admin = :admin")
```

And it renders as:

```
select rollout0_.id as id1_8_, rollout0_.version as version2_8_, rollout0_.bts_nb_all as bts_nb_a3_8_, rollout0_.country_id as country_9_8_, rollout0_.creation_datetime as creation4_8_, rollout0_.description as descript5_8_, rollout0_.end_datetime as end_date6_8_, rollout0_.name as name7_8_, rollout0_.operator_id as operato10_8_, rollout0_.start_datetime as start_da8_8_ from rollout rollout0_ cross join rollout_admin rolloutadm1_ where rollout0_.id=rolloutadm1_.rollout_id and rolloutadm1_.admin_id=1 order by rollout0_.name asc limit 10;
```

But this triggers the exception:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.country, r.operator, r.name, r.description, r.creationDatetime, r.startDatetime, r.endDatetime FROM Rollout r, RolloutAdmin ra, BTS b WHERE b.rollout.id = r.id AND r.id = ra.rollout.id AND ra.admin = :admin GROUP BY r.id")
```

And it renders as:

```
select distinct rollout0_.id as col_0_0_, rollout0_.country_id as col_1_0_, rollout0_.operator_id as col_2_0_, rollout0_.name as col_3_0_, rollout0_.description as col_4_0_, rollout0_.creation_datetime as col_5_0_, rollout0_.start_datetime as col_6_0_, rollout0_.end_datetime as col_7_0_, country3_.id as id1_4_0_, operator4_.id as id1_6_1_, country3_.version as version2_4_0_, country3_.code as code3_4_0_, country3_.list_order as list_ord4_4_0_, country3_.name as name5_4_0_, operator4_.version as version2_6_1_, operator4_.country_id as country_9_6_1_, operator4_.description as descript3_6_1_, operator4_.image as image4_6_1_, operator4_.messenger as messenge5_6_1_, operator4_.name as name6_6_1_, operator4_.operator_id as operator7_6_1_, operator4_.url as url8_6_1_ from rollout rollout0_ inner join country country3_ on rollout0_.country_id=country3_.id inner join operator operator4_ on rollout0_.operator_id=operator4_.id cross join rollout_admin rolloutadm1_ cross join bts bts2_ where bts2_.rollout_id=rollout0_.id and rollout0_.id=rolloutadm1_.rollout_id and rolloutadm1_.admin_id=1 group by rollout0_.id order by rollout0_.name asc limit 10;
```

How come such a difference ? Any way to specify the properties to be returned without fetching the whole dependent parent properties ?

EDIT: I now understand, thanks to Nizet, that I need to return an object of the same type as my repository method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
SELECT r FROM Rollout r
```

means: I want this query to return r, of type Rollout. The query returns a `List<Rollout>`.

Whereas

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.country, r.operator, r.name, r.description, r.creationDatetime, r.startDatetime, r.endDatetime FROM Rollout r
```

means: I want this query to return many different things: an ID, a country, an operator, etc. Since the query returns many different things, of different types, and potentially from several different entities (not the case in this specific example, but you could also return properties from `ra`), the query returns a `List<Object[]>`, where the first element of the array of objects is ID, the second is country, the third is operator, etc.

Not that even your first query is more complex than it should. The association between the two entities already says how the two entities are joined. So all you need is

```
SELECT r FROM RolloutAdmin ra join ra.rollout r WHERE ra.admin = :admin
```

Comment: It makes sense. But since my query returns: public Page<Rollout> can't it get it that it's a rollout ?

Comment: So, in a resource assembler environment, where the object cannot be cast to a rollout, one has to use the SELECT r FROM form and cannot have specific columns ?

Comment: The entity manager doesn't know what your method returns. All it knows is the query you pass it as argument. And yes, if you want your query to return Rollot instances, your query must select the alias or a Rollout. Not a list of properties.

Comment: All right, I guess I'll give a try to a QueryDSL as my original query has properties resulting of sum and count functions.

Comment: I don't see how QueryDSL would help. A query returning arrays of objects won't magically become a query returning Rollout instances just because it has been created with QueryDSL. And anyway, how could you get back your 4 count/sum values returned by the query if the query returned you instances of Rollout?

Comment: So there's no way to have this sort of query in JPA ?

Comment: Of course there is a way. The query you have works fine. Your code is buggy, that's all. It tries to cast an array of objects, containing the results you asked in the query to, Rollout. Don't do this cast, and get the information you need from the array of objects instead. You don't come to the conclusion that Strings can't be used in Java just because `String s = (String) new Integer(1)` throws an exception, do you?

Comment: Wow ! I always assumed I had to return an entity type. Indeed, I'll go for an array of objects then. Had a break reading your blog and the Ninja team.

Comment: By the way, should my sql statement fetch (like I did) all the properties of a rollout entity plus the 4 calculated ones ? Or have a separate sql statement for the 4 calculated one ? I chose the former, trying to avoid an 1+n pattern in my AngularJS application. But you may have a better outlook on this.

Comment: A single query, most of the time, is better than 2. But you can also use `select r, count(...), sum(...), ...`. You'll get arrays of objects, containing a Rollout instance at index 0.

Comment: I edited my question as I'm trying to use a DTO matching the properties of the select statement.

Comment: Don't turn your initial question into a different one. Ask a new question.

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564616/jpa-query-validation-fails-on-select-new-dto-statement